# Set a time range on automagic time input with cakephp

Tags: forms, cakephp, time, range, limit

I'm creating a booking form for a restaurant. It's all sussed except for one detail: I want to limit the time range of the time inputs to the opening hours of the store, yet I haven't been able to find anything on google or here. Say I want to limit it from 5pm-11pm. How do?

This is what I've got so far. The time input is first.

```
<div id="secondLine">
We'll be there at <?php echo $form->input('bookingTime', array('selected' => '19:30:00', 'interval' => '15', )); ?> on the <?php echo $form->input('bookingDate', array('dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'separator' => '', 'minYear' => '2011')); ?>
</div>
```

Thanks!

~Harley

Comment: HTH.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984061/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-date-in-a-cakephp-date-form-input